# Obtain value from a local list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to tag the docker swarm instances using terraform
I defined variable and locals as
**variables.tf**

```
variable "instance_count" {
  default = "3"
}
variable "instance_type" {
  default = "t2.micro"
}
variable "aws_region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}
variable "ami" {
  default = "ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7"
}
variable "host_name" {
  type    = map(number)
  default = {
    "Manager" = 1
    "Worker" = 2
  }
}
```

When i refer to this list's each value to assign it as a tag to ec2 instance like this
**ec2instance.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "swarm_instance" {
  count           = var.instance_count
  ami             = var.ami
  instance_type   = var.instance_type
  key_name        = aws_key_pair.dockerswarm.key_name

  tags = {
    Name = "Swarm_Instance-${count.index + 1}"
  }
   tags = {
    Name = "${local.expanded_names}"
  }
locals {
  expanded_names = {
    for name, count in var.host_name : name => [
      for i in range(count) : format("%s-%02d", name, i+1)
    ]
  }
}
```

Terraform complains
`local.expanded_names is object with 2 attributes`
I tried with `${local.expanded_names.value}`, but then it complained  `object does not have an attribute named "value"`.
So how to retrieve the value from the list when value attribute is not available in terraform.

Comment: How are you iterating over the `expanded_names` local? Ideally your question should form a [mcve] which makes it easier to understand how to reproduce your specific issue and point out where you might have made a mistake.

Comment: What is the full code where you are using your `tags`?

Comment: I have updated the code above as per the comments. I want to get the value of the locals expanded_names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags should be strings, in your case I would use `jsonencode` to get a string out of that object you are building, see my sample code below

```
variable "host_name" {
  type    = map(number)
  default = {
    "Manager" = 1
    "Worker" = 2
  }
}

locals {
  expanded_names = jsonencode({
    for name, count in var.host_name : name => [
      for i in range(count) : format("%s-%02d", name, i+1)
    ]
  })
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami           = "ami-1c761163"
  instance_type = "r5.large"

  tags = {
    Terraformed = "true"
    Name        = local.expanded_names
  }
}
```

if we run a terraform plan on that, here is what we get:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.instance will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-1c761163"
      ...
      + instance_state                       = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                        = "r5.large"
      ...
      + subnet_id                            = (known after apply)
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name"        = jsonencode(
                {
                  + Manager = [
                      + "Manager-01",
                    ]
                  + Worker  = [
                      + "Worker-01",
                      + "Worker-02",
                    ]
                }
            )
          + "Terraformed" = "true"
        }
```

---

Or maybe what you meant to do is create an array of names:

- Manager-01
- Worker-01
- Worker-02

Then use that as the instance names... if that is the case your expanded_names should not be an object `{}` but an array `[]`, then we use that instead of your count, see code sample below:

```
variable "host_name" {
  type    = map(number)
  default = {
    "Manager" = 1
    "Worker" = 2
  }
}

locals {
  expanded_names = flatten([
    for name, count in var.host_name : [
      for i in range(count) : format("%s-%02d", name, i+1)
    ]
  ])
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  for_each = toset(local.expanded_names)

  ami           = "ami-1c761163"
  instance_type = "r5.large"

  tags = {
    Terraformed = "true"
    Name        = each.value
  }
}
```

and a terraform plan on that outputs:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.instance["Manager-01"] will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-1c761163"
      ...
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name"        = "Manager-01"
          + "Terraformed" = "true"
        }
      ...
    }

  # aws_instance.instance["Worker-01"] will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-1c761163"
      ...
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name"        = "Worker-01"
          + "Terraformed" = "true"
        }
      ...
    }

  # aws_instance.instance["Worker-02"] will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-1c761163"
      ...
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Name"        = "Worker-02"
          + "Terraformed" = "true"
        }
      ...
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @helder-sepulveda. I have followed your suggestion but could not retrieve the value from the encoded json string to be used as the instance tag. Please see https://prnt.sc/1325fuw

Comment: @RaviKumarCH your image looks good, what exactly where you expecting? ... your expanded_names is an object if we need a string and we encode to json it will be just that

Comment: @RaviKumarCH see my edits to the answer above ... I think you wanted the expanded_names as an array and then loop over the names

Comment: Excellent, that worked.. thank you again @helder-sepulveda